# make upload stuck on osx 10.10 bare-arduino-project

Tags: arduino, osx-yosemite, avrdude

I followed the instructions in [here](https://github.com/WeAreLeka/Bare-Arduino-Project/blob/master/INSTALL.md), including to use arduino IDE v 1.0.5, but when I tried to `make upload` it stuck. I can upload it when using Arduino IDE.

Here is what I got:

```
  mkdir -p /Users/bagustrihatmaja/Documents/Projects/MyAwesomeProject/bin/mega328/mySecondProject
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make reset
 /Users/bagustrihatmaja/Documents/Projects/MyAwesomeProject/Arduino-Makefile/bin/ard-reset-arduino  /dev/cu.usbmodem1421
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make do_upload
 /usr/local/bin/avrdude -q -V -D -p atmega328p -c arduino -b 57600 -P /dev/cu.usbmodem1421 \
        -U flash:w:/Users/bagustrihatmaja/Documents/Projects/MyAwesomeProject/bin/mega328/mySecondProject/mySecondProject.hex:i
```

What did I miss?

I use: Bare-Arduino-Project, OSX 10.10, XCode 5, Arduino Uno, [my Makefile](http://pastebin.com/cR79Sqqz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the maintainer of the Bare-Arduino-Project, thanks for using it :)

the problem is with your Makefile:

```
BOARD_TAG         = mega328
# it should be
BOARD_TAG         = uno
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This project is awesome! I am sorry for misreading the instruction

Comment: my pleasure :) do not hesitate to star and spread the world ;)